# (1+x)^x Maclaurin series

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

i need maclaurin series up to 5 part. How can I find n-th derivative of this function? Or I just take 5 logarithmic derivatives?
Sorry for bad English

Comment: One route (though there may be an easier way) is indeed to write it as $e^{x \log(1+x)}$. Now, expand $\log(1+x)$ and then multiply that expansion by $x$ and then put that expression into the expansion for the exponential. Did you already try this?

Comment: No I haven’t, thank you, I will try this one

Answer (score 1):

Exponentialize!

$(1+x)^x = e^{x \ln(1+x)}$

Now since the McLaurin series is the series for $x \to 0$, we take the exponential series:

$$e^{x\ln(1+x)} \approx 1 + x\ln(1+x) + \frac{1}{2!}(x\ln(1+x))^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

Now we use the logarithm expansion, up to the second order, since $x\to 0$:

$$\ln(1+x) \approx x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

And we substitute:

$$1 + x\left(x - \frac{x^2}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2!}\left(x^2\left(x - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2\right)$$

Now you can do the maths by yourself, and neglecting terms major than $x^3$ you get the fist terms:

$$1 + x^2 - \frac{x^3}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$$

If you are interested in more terms, here they are:

$$1+x^2-\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{5 x^4}{6}-\frac{3 x^5}{4}+\frac{33 x^6}{40}-\frac{5 x^7}{6}+\frac{2159 x^8}{2520}+O\left(x^9\right)$$